# Show closest release date titles using foreach-array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm working on a *game release section*, where I display games that are about to release. I only work with game information, and a release date.

My array looks like this (actual array has a lot more info so this is just a replicate):

```
$arr = [
    [
        'id' => 'UP0006-CUSA08724_00-BATTLEFIELDV0000',
        'attributes' => [
            'name' => 'Battlefield V [test1]',
            'thumbnail-url-base' => 'https://store.playstation.com/store/api/chihiro/00_09_000/container/US/en/999/UP0006-CUSA08724_00-BATTLEFIELDV0000/1539651459000/image'
            'release-date' => '2018-12-14T00:00:00Z'
        ],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'UP0006-CUSA08724_00-BATTLEFIELDV0000',
        'attributes' => [
            'name' => 'Battlefield V [test2]',
            'thumbnail-url-base' => 'https://store.playstation.com/store/api/chihiro/00_09_000/container/US/en/999/UP0006-CUSA08724_00-BATTLEFIELDV0000/1539651459000/image'
            'release-date' => '2018-10-14T00:00:00Z'
        ],
    ],
    [
        'id' => 'UP0006-CUSA08724_00-BATTLEFIELDV0000',
        'attributes' => [
            'name' => 'Battlefield V [test3]',
            'thumbnail-url-base' => 'https://store.playstation.com/store/api/chihiro/00_09_000/container/US/en/999/UP0006-CUSA08724_00-BATTLEFIELDV0000/1539651459000/image'
            'release-date' => '2019-10-14T00:00:00Z'
        ],
    ],
];
```

I want to **display the game titles that are closest to release to the current date** such as [test1], and **skip the ones that have been released already** such as [test2].

I've tried to skip them using this line:

```
if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime($title['attributes']['release-date'])) continue;
```

But for some reason it does not seem to skip them, and just keeps them in.

Also I have no idea where to start when trying to show the game titles that are closest to release to the current date.

My full code:

```
foreach($json['included'] as $key => $title) {
    $cusa = substr(explode('-', $title['id'], 3)[1], 0, -3);

    if($title['type'] == 'game' && substr($cusa, 0, 4) == 'CUSA') {
        // if the day of release has already passed, skip
        if (strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')) > strtotime($title['attributes']['release-date'])) continue;
            ?>
            <div class="game-banner" style="background:url(<?php echo $title['attributes']['thumbnail-url-base']; ?>)">
                <h4 class="psplus-game-name"><?php echo $title['attributes']['name']; ?></h4>
            </div>
            <?php
            if($key >= 4) break; // display only 3
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your problem might be timezones. The time strings in your data are UTC. If PHP's default timezone isn't also UTC, then `date('Y-m-d H:i:s')` will give you your local timezone, and the comparison won't work correctly. Lots of different ways to approach this, easiest might be to just use `gmdate()` instead of `date()`.

Comment: You might also think about using `DateTime` objects instead of the ints that `strtotime()` returns, as the `DateTime` objects can be compared directly.

Comment: Hmm, good point. Will give it a try and let you know @AlexHowansky

Comment: "does not seem to skip" is a very bad error description. Check out [mcve], which gives instructions how to reduce the problem to its essence.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt disagree. I believe this question has all it needs. (Almost) correctly formatted array, a clear expected output and correctly formatted code. What is it you are missing?

Comment: The question lacks code that can be taken and executed without having to change anything. As it stands, it is incomplete and thus also not verifiable. Also, the error description is there, but it still requires interpretation. Instead, it should describe what observations are expected.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I appreciate you trying to help out, but in my opinion that's just not needed here and feels more like nitpicking to gain an on-site reward (or similar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to calculate the seconds left to release date, and if it's a positive number echo it.

```
foreach($arr as $game){
    $timeleft = strtotime($game['attributes']['release-date'])-time();
    if($timeleft>0) echo floor($timeleft/86400) ." days left to ".$game['attributes']['name'] ." \n";
}

//58 days left to Battlefield V [test1] 
//362 days left to Battlefield V [test3]
```

https://3v4l.org/OMetR

If your initial array is unsorted and you want then sorted you can add them to an array with key being the timeleft and sort on keys with ksort().

```
foreach($arr as $game){
    $timeleft = strtotime($game['attributes']['release-date'])-time();
    if($timeleft>0) $games[$timeleft] = floor($timeleft/86400) ." days left to ".$game['attributes']['name'] ." \n";
}

ksort($games);
echo implode("", $games);
```

https://3v4l.org/gbLCs